# Win32Exception of SetTimer in C# form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

My C# Windows Forms Application raises a Win32 exception related to `SetTimer`.
But I have no idea where `SetTimer` would have been called.

The following is the exception details:

The form application surely has a timer to process tasks periodically.

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>
> Stack: 
>       at MS.Win32.SafeNativeMethods.SetTimer(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Int32)
>       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.SetWin32Timer(Int32)
>       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.UpdateWin32TimerFromDispatcherThread(System.Object)
>       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.UpdateWin32Timer()
>       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.AddTimer(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer)
>       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.Restart()
>       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.Start()
>       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CommitChannelAfterNextVSync()
>       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.NotifyPresented(System.Windows.Media.Composition.MIL_PRESENTATION_RESULTS, Int64, Int32)
>       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.NotifyChannelMessage()
>       at System.Windows.Media.MediaContextNotificationWindow.MessageFilter(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
>       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
>       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
>       at MyApplication.Program.Main()

supplement: the Program.cs has the following exception handling code:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(UIThreadException);
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledException);
...
}

...

private static void UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Unhandled Exception: " + sender.ToString() + "\n" + e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
}
private static void UIThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
{
MessageBox.Show("UIThreadException: " + sender.ToString() + "\n" + t.Exception.ToString(), "UIThreadException!!!!", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
//Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: What's the Win32Exception.Message and Win32Exception.NativeErrorCode?

Comment: I dont know the Message and NativeErrorCode. The exception information is obtained from Windows event log, which also says the exception is happening in C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll. The error seems to be happening repeatedly, maybe it is related to resource release? But I am not sure why the timer is related.

Comment: Add [AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) handler to get more info.

Comment: It seems you're using a WPF component which uses DispatcherTimer, which in turn calls SetTimer. It's unclear however, why this is failing. See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/WindowsBase/Shared/MS/Win32/SafeNativeMethodsCLR.cs.html#298 for reference. Maybe you could p/invoke GetLastError in your exception handler: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes! there is really a WPF component I am using in the form for 3D displaying of an equipment movement (simple rotation). I will try to check the component, and add some exception handling code.

Comment: @Chengting, you can add extra code for getting more details from exception in your UnhandledException and UIThreadException. Something like var we =  ExceptionObject as Win32Exception. if (we != null) WriteToLog("Exception: {0}. Message: {1}, NativeCode: {2}", we, we.Message and we.NativeErrorCode)